# how to work with uneven dates in Excel?

Tags: excel

I needed help as I am trouble with this recurring problem.

I have following date formats. American date format:

```
8/30/2013
11/1/2014
1/12/2014
```

For 8/30/2013 , I write `=DATE(RIGHT(B2;4);LEFT(B2;1);MID(B2;3;2))`, and I get it as "2013-08-30". For the other dates, I have to manually rewrite them again and again.

How can I write in one line to get  **8**/30/2013 or **10**/12/2014 in a final date result like "2013-xx-xx?

Comment: but are those really dates? not text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used string manipulation formulas and it worked for your first date, I believe that the date is actually text format.

As such, I would suggest using `FIND` to get the positions of `/` like this:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(B2;4);LEFT(B2;FIND("/";B2)-1);MID(B2;FIND("/";B2)+1;FIND("/";B2;FIND("/";B2)+1)-FIND("/";B2)-1))
```

It's quite long, I admit, but it's quite difficult to get substrings between two specific characters. If the year is always in that format, then you can use a slightly shorter formula:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(B2;4);LEFT(B2;FIND("/";B2)-1);MID(B2;FIND("/";B2)+1;LEN(B2)-5-FIND("/";B2)))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. That is an amazing thing.  I will try understanding the code now. Didnt expect to find FIND and LEN in this. Surprised.thank you.

Comment: @user3197575 You're welcome. You can mark an answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves your problem. You will be getting 2 points for this, and will also mark your question as solved :)

Comment: @user3197575 You should find the outline of a tick like this: [link to picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pLoTA.png). Click that tick and it'll become green, the mark for an answer of being accepted.

Comment: I had a question about the code, I tried figuring it out on my own, but I dont understand it: What does this bit do? -> "LEN(B2)-5-FIND("/";B2)". I understand LEN takes the length of B2,which is 9. Then I dont understand the purpose of "-5-FIND("/";B2)". Could you explain if it is possible for you?

Comment: @user3197575 Sure. We know that the year in the date contains at least 4 numbers, and there is a slash there too, so that makes 5 characters. So the length of the month+/+date must be the total length of the text, minus the year (4) minus the last slash (1). `FIND("/";B2)` now gives the position of the first slash, which is also the number of characters with dates and the first slash. So, in the end `LEN(B2)-5-FIND("/";B2)` gives the length of the date.

Answer (score 1):

if all entries are dates, you can use `Text` function:

```
=TEXT(B2, "yyy-mm-dd")
```

hope this helps.

Comment: btw, use `;` in place of `,` if it is your default separator.